# Pension rights post Brexit

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, social-security

[In the EU](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/retire-abroad/state-pensions-abroad/index_en.htm#shortcut-4), if you worked in another member state for a period of time, that period will add to the minimum amount of time you need to work to be able to claim pension from another member state (with the amount taking into account the time worked in that member state only).

Now that UK has left the EU, is the time worked in the UK before it left the EU (or after, for people with withdrawal agreement rights) taken into account for future EU pension's minimum time and vice versa?